# How can i match values from dictionary in Django template

Tags: python, django

I have dictionary like this

```
mydict['student'] = {'name':'john', 'age':'36'}
```

IN my template i have the list of students like this

```
{{ object.students}}
```

I am displaying the list of students in the table like this

```
<table>
{% for student in object.students %}
<tr><td>{{student.name}}</td>
{% endfor%}
```

I have the complex scenario and i have to match the student name and age or whatever keys are in `mydict` and if that matches only then show the student row otherwise no

Like this

```
if mydict.student.name == student.name &&  mydict.student.age == student.age
```

then show the row

The thing is i can have the variable number of keys in dictoanry so basically i am looking for something like `filter` or `whatever` to which i pass the `dictionary` and object and it return me either true or false. something like

```
if getResult(mydict['student'], student)

def getResut(a,b):
    result_list =[]
    for key in a:
       if b[key] icontains a[key]:
           result_list.append(True)
       else
           return False or result_list.append(False)
```

It will return me the list of true or Flase as list . Then i will check if all are true then it will return True othwise it will return False

I have to do all that in either `template` or `filters`

Comment: Any reason you "have to do all that" in your template ? Also, is `object.students` a `Queryset` ?

Comment: yes that is the query set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/):

```
@register.filter(name='show_student')
def show_student(obj, d):
    show = True
    for key, val in d.iteritems():
        if hasattr(obj, key):
            obj_val = getattr(key, obj)
            if obj_val != val:
                show = False
                break
        else:
            show = False
            break
    return show
```

Then in template you can do:

```
{% if student|show_student:my_dict %}
    # show student
{% endif %}
```

P.S: you have to be careful that the dictionary should contains attribute values of same type e.g. 'age':'36' in this age is a string, usually it should be an integer value